# The Eastern Catholicism tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've recently created some questions on Catholicism, and while I refer to Roman Catholicism, I don't want to necessarily exclude Eastern Catholicism or anything in full communion with Roman atholicism (i.e. I don't necessarily refer only to Roman Catholicism).

1. Does the [Catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism) tag necessarily refer to and only to the Roman Catholic Church in that it excludes [Eastern Catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-catholicism)?
2. Is there any particular reason we have the [Eastern Catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-catholicism) tag instead of just specifying that Catholicism includes Eastern Catholicism (and anything in full communion with Roman Catholicism)? Eh, I guess if we do this, then we should unite tags pertaining to denominations according to what's full communion with what. idk.

Ostensibly related...maybe not really: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32778/how-come-we-got-rid-of-the-tag-coin-but-not-dice-poker-etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism) tag includes both Roman rite and Eastern Catholic churches. The [eastern-catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-catholicism) tag exists because people have found it useful in the past. There's no particular reason why we don't have [western-catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/western-catholicism) or [roman-rite](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman-rite) tags, just that nobody wanted to add them previous. In their absence, and without a tag like [eastern-catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eastern-catholicism), it's normally a good assumption that a question tagged [catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism) refers to the whole Catholic Church or possibly more specifically to the Western Catholic church as it is by far the largest.

Comment: Thanks curiousdannii♦! when did you become a moderator by the way? i could swear i've seen your username before but you weren't a moderator then. or maybe it was in another site

Comment: congratulations on becoming a mod! i remember seeing you in other posts in christianity se and elsewhere on se.